# Trying to evaluate a series

Tags: power-series

I know that :

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} \binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n4^n}= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2n4^n}=\ln(4)$$

But I have no idea on how to prove it ! Is it a well-known series ?

I need it for a second calculation of a Dirichlet integral :

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$

Where I'm using series development and Wallis integral. (I don't need help on this, this is just for context, I'm curious)

Comment: If that sum includes an $n=0$ term it diverges, but if by $\Bbb N^\ast$ you meant $n\ge1$ you can write the series as $\int_0^{1/4}\frac{dx}{x}\left((1-4x)^{-1/2}-1\right)$.

Comment: This looks vaguely likely the Taylor series for the logarithm. Perhaps it's related via some series acceleration formula? Alternatively, this should follow from the fact $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^{n}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They gave all the hints in the comments.

For $|x|<\frac14$, we have the Maclaurin series
$$(1-4x)^{-\frac12}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{-\frac12\choose n}(-4x)^n1^{-\frac12-n}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\frac12)(-\frac32)...(-\frac{2n-1}2)}{n!}(-1)^n4^nx^n\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1.3.5...(2n-1)}{2^n n!}4^nx^n\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^n2^n\,n!n!}4^nx^n\\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n\choose n}x^n\tag1
$$
From $(1)$ we can obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{2n\choose n}x^{n-1}=
\frac{(1-4x)^{-\frac12}-1}x.\tag2$$
Integrating $(2)$ from $0$ to $\frac14$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{2n\choose n}\frac1{n4^n}=\int_0^{1/4}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)\frac{dx}x\\\stackrel{x=\frac{\sin^2\theta}4}{=}2\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\tan(\tfrac\theta 2)d\theta=2\ln2.$$

Comment: I absolutely don't understand the link between $I=\int_0^{1/4}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)\frac{dx}x$ and the initial series. But I agree with your equalities.

Comment: THANK YOU for that great edit, I understood everything

Comment: I didnt understand the connection of this with the second calculation. Can you give more details in OP?@LexLarn